# Does definition list <dl> require that each <dd> will have <dt> tag?

Tags: html, html-lists

Does  definition list `<dl>` require that each `<dd>` will have `<dt>` tag?

Example:

**option1** for each `<dd>` exist his `<dt>` also if `<dt>` empty:

```
<dl>
<dt></dt>
<dd>value1</dd>
<dt>name2</dt>
<dd>value2</dd>
</dl>
```

**option2** for each `<dd>` not exist his `<dt>` if `<dt>` empty:

```
<dl>

<dd>value1</dd>
<dt>name2</dt>
<dd>value2</dd>
</dl>
```

---

---

**Edit:**

Example for when dt can be empty (its build by zend_form auto - can not be changed):

```
<dl> 

<dt><lable>Last Name:</label></dt> 
<dd><input type='text' size='30' /></dd>
<dt><lable></label></dt> 
<dd><input type='submit' size='30' value='submit'/></dd>
<dt><lable>Name:</label></dt> 
<dd><input type='text' size='30' /></dd>

</dl>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[HTML 4](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/lists.html#h-10.3) doesn't enforce this, neither is [XHTML 1.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml-modularization/abstract_modules.html#s_listmodule). They only require `<dl>` contains only one or more `<dt>` or `<dd>`s.

However, [HTML 5 has stricter requirement](https://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/dl):

> zero or more of: (one or more `<dt>` elements, *followed by* one or more `<dd>` elements)

Hence, your option2 will not validate in HTML 5.

option1 is still fine, as `<dt>` can contain any "phrasing content", including empty content.

Answer (score 3):

According to [the HTML 4 DTD](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/sgml/dtd.html):

```
<!ELEMENT DL - - (DT|DD)+              -- definition list -->
```

That means you can mix and match.

Here is a nice overview of the various ways to use a definition list:

- http://www.benmeadowcroft.com/webdev/articles/definition-lists.shtml

Comment: +1, this is the most definitive resource. Is there a good introduction to interpreting DTD syntax somewhere?

Comment: @Pekka: Straight-forward and sufficient -  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Type_Definition#Element_type_declarations ;-)

Answer (score 2):

A `dl` containing only `dd`s validates in the [W3C validator](http://validator.w3.org/), so I guess it's okay.

W3C HTML 4.01 Reference: [10.1 Introduction to lists](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/lists.html)

Working example:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<title>Untitled</title>
</head>
<body>
  <dl>
   <dd>value1</dd>
   <dd>value2</dd>
 </dl>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The  tag is used in
conjunction with  (defines
the definition list) and 
(describes the item in the list).
Copied from W3.

Answer (score 1):

It is valid, but I can't see why you'd ever want to do it.

Note that your second example only really applies to the first item; there is no such thing as a missing `dt` later on, as multiple `dd` items can apply for a single `dt`.

Comment: Example for my case that explain better:

<dl>
<dt><lable>Name:</label></dt>
<dd><input type='text' size='30' />
<dt><lable></label></dt>
<dd><input type='submit' size='30' value='submit'/>
</dl>